# PHP openssl free key deprecated

Tags: php

In php the function

```
openssl_free_key
```

is deprecated and not includde in php 8. Can somebody give an alternative for it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> This function is now deprecated as it doesn't have an effect anymore.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-free-key.php

> PHP 8 deprecates openssl_free_key (actually openssl_pkey_free which it aliases) and automatically destroys the key instance when it goes out of scope.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-free.php#125655

So really you replace it with nothing, as the resource is now cleaned up properly the same as anything else.

If you want to *feel* like you're going that extra mile you can call `unset()` on it, but that's not a thing I would consider necessary.

Answer (score 4):

In case you need to maintain compatibility with older php version, you can do something like this:

```
// $privateKey = openssl_pkey_new([ ... ]);

if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 80000) {
    openssl_free_key($privateKey);
}
```